# Float Point Number Rounding with round and pow functions

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that rounds a number to a certain decimal place that was specified by the user. It is a requirement to do this with both `cout.fset` and `cout.precision`, as well as with `round` and `pow` functions. In the end, the output of the program should be something like this:

```
123.4567
2
123.46
123.46
```

My main function used `cout.fset` and `cout.precision`, and it works fine. The problem is my `double rounding` function which uses `round` and `pow`. For some reason I am getting the following output:

```
123.4567
2
123.46
0.00
```

Why is it printing just zeros in that last line? I am new to programming and C++ as a whole so I would appreciate your help. Thank you. (I have a feeling it is a minor/beginner mistake I am overlooking but this is the extent of my knowledge at the moment)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double rounding(int pp){
    double d;
    double k = std::pow(10, pp);
    
    return std::round(d * k) / k;
}

int main(){
    double p;
    double d, round;
    
    cin >> d;
    cin >> p;
    
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(p);
    
    cout << d << endl;
    
    round = rounding(d);
    cout << round << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program has _undefined behavior_, you're using an uninitialized variable `d` in your function.

Comment: Naming a variable the same name in a different scope does not make it share the same value. Its a totally unrelated variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d` in the `rounding` function is not initialized and have indeterminate value.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double rounding(double d, int pp){
    double k = std::pow(10, pp);
    
    return std::round(d * k) / k;
}

int main(){
    double p;
    double d, round;
    
    cin >> d;
    cin >> p;
    
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(p);
    
    cout << d << endl;
    
    round = rounding(d, d);
    cout << round << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```